# Doing a nav.push to same page results in odd transition effect in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

Working on an app that is a game of sorts with several levels, each level has roughly 20 questions.

Rather than make a page for each question I made a page for each level then subdivided that page in the template via angular's switch statement as so:

```
<div id="level-2-screen-3" *ngSwitchCase="3"> // The content </div>
<div id="level-2-screen-4" *ngSwitchCase="4"> // The content </div>
```

The switch case in this instance is going off of the current question number.

This has worked well except for page transitions where because the question number is getting increased between nav.pushes that means that the 'incoming' page that's coming in from left to right now looks the same as the 'previous' page. So it looks like the same page is overlapping itself.

The only solution I can come up with is to create an alt for each level that has the same code but which is alternated between nav.pushes, this way it's always going to a new page...

So the page pushes would look like

Level1Page

Level1AltPage

Level1Page

Level1AltPage

as opposed to

Level1Page

Level1Page

Level1Page

Level1Page

Curious if anyone had a potentially better solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question brings to mind age old computer wisdom:

> Instead of reducing latency, hide it.

-- *Principles of Computer System Design: An Introduction, Saltzer and Kaashoek*

In your case, the principle may encourage some out of the box thinking.  Why not show an overlay that covers your whole screen (or maybe just the questions themselves) with a cool loading graphic?  Even a pixelated 'censored' look over the questions could work nicely, and add some light suspense.  Merely hook into some of Ionic's [page load events](https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/) to show and hide it - e.g.

- Set a boolean class property `isPageLoading` in `ionViewWillLeave` that shows your loading/transition state, then
- Clear it in `ionViewWillEnter` or `ionViewDidEnter`.